# Recover Data from Boot Looping OnePlus6

Tags: recovery-mode, oneplus, oneplus-6

I have a OnePlus 6 (all stock except developer options enabled) that randomly started doing a boot loop in the night, I CANNOT lose the data from this phone, any suggestions to recover it?
We are in the middle of renovating a house and the photos and videos on there are our proof to building control that certain things have been done correctly, without these we will be in some trouble.

Cheers.

Comment: try to get logcat for more info. don't try anything you have read - it won't work

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what any of that means, it's been MANY years since I've done anything remotely to do with command line etc.... I'd need talking through it step by step

Comment: you need PC and [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) for [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#Syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that, I have downloaded ADB, what now?

Comment: logcat says no connected devices

Comment: I am afraid this is dead end. but you can view logs in recovery mode maybe

Comment: So is there no other way to recover the data?

Comment: @Mogs84 whatever data that was back up in your Google account is all that you can lay your hands on. It sucks but Android is designed in a way to not allow the owner to access their data for no fault of theirs. Just because of some software or hardware failure.

Comment: the way to recover data off device is, fix the boot-loop and let it boot into stage with access to data. your best options are switching slots (fallback to healthy slot) or install OTA zip from recovery (will hopefully fix it). sometimes only wiping cache partition is enough - you can try first

Comment: Thanks Alecxs, have tried all viable options via the recovery mode, reluctand to try factory reset from recovery just yet incase any other option turns up.
How would I install an OTA zip from recovery?

Comment: I am not sure. usually copy zip to MicroSD then chose *"Apply update from SD card"* but adb sideload may work with *"Apply update from ADB"* https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3792244

Comment: I'm trying the guide here: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/oneplus-factory-image-creation-guide/ and got through everything required to get to flash stage, getting error saying "FAILED (remote: Flashing is not allowed in Lock State)
finished. total time: 1.628s"